# Cross-Domain link authentication using JWT

Tags: security, cross-domain, jwt

I have a link that contains a parameter `token` which is the JWT token that will be validated across another domain. I'm struggling with the fact that a user can copy and share that link across several browsers or with other users.

The jwt payload looks like the following:

```
{
  "userId": "46",
  "role": "User",
  "nbf": 1589877059,
  "exp": 1589963459,
  "iat": 1589877059
}
```

My goal is to secure that link from being shared other than the current user while authenticating that user on the second domain.

Am i missing something or is there any other way to secure a link across different domains? Any suggestion is really appreciated.

**Update**

An approach I'm trying is storing the last active `SessionId` in the database and validating it on both sides. In case the token is valid and actual `SessionId` is different from the last active id, then redirect to some unauthorized page. but the drawback is that the user will require session-authentication instead of cookie authentication since the session will reset each time the user closes the browser but the cookie will remain the same.

Comment: So you want to authenticate a user from a link only, but... not allow authentication with the link only? :)

Comment: Did not get you... the link contains a parameter token which is the jwt passed from domain `A` to domain `B` to let the user browse some page on `B`. @GaborLengyel